How to pace learning on PhD
I am starting an interdisciplinary PhD  this year on protein modelling would like to ask how one normally goes about structuring their learning on a PhD.
Background: I have just done a 3 year Bachelor's (UK) in mathematics. At undergrad I clarified every detail and did all the questions on each course to make sure there were no gaps in my knowledge for the exam. The PhD contains information in Biology and Physics and I only have high-school knowledge in these.
Therefore I feel I have lots of gaps when I go through a paper or a monograph. I am not sure if I should try and understand the gaps or just move on once I get the general idea. My supervisor has told me I will not sit any exams and start research straight anyway.

The short answer to your question is yes, you should "just move on once I get the general idea" and you should not "try and understand the gaps".
It is very common to feel like the way that you are feeling when starting out in research.  This is especially the case in interdisciplinary fields, but it also common for new PhD students doing a PhD in the same field they did their undergraduate degree in.
Doing scientific research invariably touches on vast amounts of background material.  But at the same time, it is surprising how little of the background material you actually need to understand at a deep level in order to effectively do research.  After some time you eventually develop a "feel" for what you need and don't need to know.  This only comes with experience.
I think a good course of action is to focus on doing research and making progress (if you already have particular project to do). Don't worry too much about knowing background material.  Unless you know so little that you don't know what you're doing, it's usually better to push forward rather than spending too much time reading and learning: often it is by doing research and seeing a project to completion that the real learning happens.  It is also a good idea to talk to people (i.e. your supervisor, other PhD students, ...) and to never be afraid to ask questions.
